# Fail to reinstall mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I removed mariadb by remove `/usr/lib/mysql` , `/etc/mysql` and uninstall mariadb server with `yaourt -Rsn maraidb`.

And mariadb(mysqld) start failed after I re-install mariadb caused by missing some files.
And the log was:

```
[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
[Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
[Note] Starting crash recovery...
[Note] Crash recovery finished.
[Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table 
mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos>
[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' 
doesn't exist
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 
'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

It seems mariadb didn't initialized successfully, but I can't figure out how to fix it. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Note after installation：
You need to initialize the MariaDB data directory prior to starting the service. This can be done with mysql_install_db command, e.g.:
  `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

DON'T FORGET IT.